# Package conflict while installing ms-sql in ubuntu. Broken packages

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu, apt

I am trying to install ms sql in Ubuntu 20.04. Even I have got it installed in 20.04 successfully following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-ver15) guide but I sometime I have this problem multiple time and not sure why is this happening.

When I try to run following commads

`curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/prod.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list`

`sudo apt-get install mssql-tools unixodbc-dev`

I end up having below errors:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>
> mssql-tools : Depends: msodbcsql17 (>= 17.3.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
>
> unixodbc-dev : Depends: unixodbc (= 2.3.7)
>
> Depends: odbcinst1debian2 (= 2.3.7) but 2.3.6-0.1build1 is to be inst
>
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

`sudo apt-cache policy <package>` shows multiple versions available for these packages. 
I tried installing the right versions for dependencies that did not help when I ran `sudo apt-get install mssql-tools unixodbc-dev` again.

When I checked `msprod.list` file, it looks like 'https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/prod' the tailed `.list` is missing so I added that(not sure I should do that or not). Then I have got everything installed.

Now when I do `sudo apt update` it ends up with below error:

> E: The repository 'https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/18.04/prod.list bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
>
> N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
>
> N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

I really don't understand what is happening and what I have to do to get thing working in simplest way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do as follow:

```
apt install mssql-tools unixodbc-dev odbcinst1debian2 msodbcsql17 unixodbc libodbc1
```

`apt-get` install stuff caring about package conflict.

If you use `apt` only it will forcefully install the package without taking care if the installation is creating conflicts.

Comment: Well, I tried this but unfortunately I'm ending up at the same issue after  `udo apt-get install mssql-tools unixodbc-dev`.(ran though root)

Comment: Ok, let's use the hammer: 'apt install mssql-tools unixodbc-dev odbcinst1debian2'

Comment: eventually `apt install mssql-tools unixodbc-dev odbcinst1debian2 msodbcsql17 unixodbc libodbc1` this installed everything at once. Why is there a version conflict

Comment: God only knows, probably some package you previously installed. If you agree with me I would like to change my reply with the right comment that made you arrive at the solution

Comment: Sure change it. I think I have done `apt upgrade` and probably it installed some new versions but did not removed older.

Comment: @Riki there was a version conflict because you used `https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/prod.list` on something that wasn't Ubuntu 18.04. On Ubuntu 20.04 you need to use `https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/prod.list`